# Динамический биндинг элементов как контент других элементов

Tags: c#, windowsphone

Есть презентация на несколько слайдов. Контент презентации делится на повторяющийся и на уникальный для каждого слайда, например:

> Слайд 1: Текст, linefeed, текст, текст
> болдом
>
> Слайд 2: Текст, текст болдом и с подчеркиванием, текст

Получается, что в каждом слайде есть какой-то элемент N, дочерние элементы которого не определены в шаблоне и зависят от данных.
Можно ли реализовать такое через обычный биндинг? В данном случае элемент N - это TextBlock (а все данные - только текст), но общие решения только приветствуются.

Comment: Ничего не понятно из вашего описания. Почему бы общие части не вынести в UserControl'ы и использовать в каждом слайде? С Binding'ами у меня всё всегда работало для контента любой сложности. MVVM всё-таки.

Comment: Прошу прощения, у меня проблемы с формулировками. Обновил.

Comment: Можно использовать несколько шаблонов и выбирать их динамически через DataTemplateSelector

Comment: @Олег Нечитайло, попробую, спасибо